How to get client's rating from vendorProposal query
we are developing web app with integration with Upwork Graphql API to display our company contracts and proposals. We need a way to get client's rating and total spent information on proposal page.
We can't find any fields for it in vendorProposal query. How can we query for client's rating and total spent information?
We found totalReviews in MarketplaceJobPostingSearchClientInfo, but this query is not what we need.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
